# What's the highest number of points without winning the Premier League?

Tags: football, trivia, history, records, english-premier-league

In the [2018-19 Premier League season](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018%E2%80%9319_Premier_League), Liverpool finished 2nd with 97 points. Has any team ever got more points than this without winning the league?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_League_records_and_statistics#Points), it is:

> - Most points in a season without winning the league: 97, Liverpool (2018–19)

It's not surprising since the record for most points is 100, only three higher (by Manchester City, the previous season).